# How to use Vim's normal mode CTRL-A number increment in visual block mode?

Tags: vim

I have a table:

```
0 | 3
1 | 4
2 | 5
```

In normal mode, I can go over `0`, hit `CTRL-A` and it becomes 1.

I want something analogous for visual block mode (in which `CTRL-A` does not increment the selection), to use it on the second column and obtain:

```
0 | 4
1 | 5
2 | 6
```

Is that possible without a macro / plugin / defining a function?

Best simple workaround so far was defining a macro, counting columns, and repeating it the right number of times, but I keep thinking: why is there no `CTRL-A` for visual block?

My initial example was:

```
a | 3
b | 4
c | 5
```

For that particular case in which the number is the first numeric row of the table, the answer given by @hawk and @romainl worked well: `:norm! ^A`, which expands to `:'<,'>norm! ^A`. Is there a way to take care of the general case?

Comment: See my edit for a more general solution.

Comment: The number can be at the cursor, or the right of the cursor(on the same line). These are the defaults for Vim.

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution?

Comment: @romainl thanks, that worked and taught me new things about Vim regexes =)

Comment: See my edit for an even better solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been added in version 8. Check out :help new-items-8

Edit: Changed the help command above.

Result of :help new-items-8

```
Visual mode commands:
v_CTRL-A        CTRL-A          add N to number in highlighted text
v_CTRL-X        CTRL-X          subtract N from number in highlighted text
v_g_CTRL-A      g CTRL-A        add N to number in highlighted text
v_g_CTRL-X      g CTRL-X        subtract N from number in highlighted text
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the commit / release note to complete the answer? I've tested and it does work.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 8):

I doubt anyone here will be able to tell you exactly *why* there's no `<C-a>` for visual block mode.

The best we can do is help you find an efficient way to achieve your goal.

Plugins like [VisIncr](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=670) by DrChip or [speeddating](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2120) by Tim Pope are specifically designed to address that "missing feature".

If your needs are relatively simple, like in your example, a simple `:norm <C-v><C-a>` could be enough. Maybe with a mapping…

```
xnoremap <C-a> :normal! ^A
```

(The `^A` is obtained with `<C-v><C-a>`.)

(edit)

A more generic approach exists but it is not very finger-friendly:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 1/g
```

You could map it, of course, and make it a little smarter:

```
xnoremap <C-a> :<C-u>let vcount = v:count ? v:count : 1 <bar> '<,'>s/\%V\d\+/\=submatch(0) + vcount <cr>gv
```

And give it a friend:

```
xnoremap <C-x> :<C-u>let vcount = v:count ? v:count : 1 <bar> '<,'>s/\%V\d\+/\=submatch(0) - vcount <cr>gv
```

With those mappings you can do `<C-a><C-a><C-a>` and `<C-x><C-x><C-x>` while retaining the visual block or `8<C-a>`/`12<C-x>`.

(endedit)

Comment: You can use `v:count1` instead of `v:count ? v:count : 1` to get 1 when no count is used.

Comment: As far as I can tell, ctrl-a in visual mode is in vim 7.4.

Comment: @contrebis, yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can run normal command on visually selected block. e.g. `:normal! ^A` then hit enter

Comment: This fix worked only if the number was the first numeric row of the column, but I was hoping for a more general solution, so I updated the question to reflect that.